# Convex functions minimized at infinity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a conjecture as below.

Suppose $\varphi(\lambda):[0,\infty)^m\to\mathbb R$ is convex and differentiable in $\lambda$ ($m$-dimensional nonnegative vector) with a finite infimum $\underline\varphi=\inf_{\lambda\ge0}\varphi(\lambda)$, and suppose it has an unbounded infimizing sequence $\{\lambda^k\}$, i.e., $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda^k_i=\infty$, $\forall i$, and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\varphi(\lambda^k)=\underline\varphi$.

Conjecture: $\lim_{k\to\infty}\nabla\varphi(\lambda^k)=0$.

For 1-dimensional space, it is very simple to prove. However, for higher dimensions, I get stuck. Could someone help?